# Magento2 - Communication link failure: 1053 Server

Tags: magento2

***I am getting this error in logs
Communication link failure: 1053 Server
shutdown in progress, query was:***

```
SELECT catalog_category_entity.* FROM catalog_category_entity
WHERE ((entity_id ='10977')) AND (catalog_category_entity.created_in <= '1574504144') AND
(catalog_category_entity.updated_in > '1574504144') [] []
```